# Grails Jasper Subreport

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using grails and I have this Jasper report with a subreport in it.
Having this simple two jasper reports

> Note: Only .jrxml is the file extension of the files inside the /web-app/reports

Main Report [main_report][subreport area]

```
<subreport>
   <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="157"/>
   <subreportExpression>
      <![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "test_report.jasper"]]>
   </subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Test report [test_report][title.band]

```
<staticText>
   <reportElement x="203" y="30" width="154" height="34"/>
   <textElement/>
   <text><![CDATA[Hello World]]></text>
</staticText>
```

And looking in the view or the gsp file I have this command

```
<g:jasperReport jasper="main_report"
                format="pdf, html"
                delimiter=" "/>
```

When I want to view the report in either PDF of HTML format, the report returns a blank page. Am I missing something to display the `main_report` properly with a subreport `test_report`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. Make sure the sub-report is compiled (do this in iReport), i.e. there should be a `.jasper` file for sub report in reports dir.
2. Set the SUBREPORT_DIR parameter before generating the report, e.g.

`params.SUBREPORT_DIR = servletContext.getRealPath('/reports') + "/"`

(assuming the compiled subreport is in the `<app>/web-app/reports` directory, the same as the uncompiled reports).

Comment: After trying your answer, the `main_report` compile on grails runtime but the `sub_report` did not. I've checked in IReport if the `main_report` displays the `sub_report` and it did. What's missing here?

Comment: Your compiled sub report (.jasper) is in reports for prior to starting grails app?

Comment: I've compiled the `sub_repoert.jrxml` to `sub_report.jasper`. I also compiled the `main_report` just to be sure yet no changes on the result. Only the `main_report' is displayed without the `sub_report`.